# Change color of entire row before or after inserting values on a sheet VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm Trying to change the value of a row when a determine condition happens, and I was thinking of doing it after the insert was made, but maybe it's easier before the insert (?) The thing is i've tried both, and i'm doing it wrong because it's not working

Code:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Site Configuration List")
       ' Tried this .Range("A").EntireRow.Interior.Color = 49407
        .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = Code
        .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = Name
        .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = "" & Contract & ""
        .Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = SiteCode
        .Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = SiteName
        .Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = Approver
        .Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = ItemCode
        .Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = RequiredQty
        .Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = ControlFlag
    If Color = 0 Then
       ', this .Offset(-1).Interior.Color = 49407
        ',this .Interior.Color = 49407
     'and this .EntireRow.Interior.Color = 255
    Else


    End If
    End With
```

Obviously not at the same time, but no of those work. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it? I'm new to VBA and some of the simplest things usually take me more time to figure out. What I've used in order to try to achieve what I want I've taken it from other similar questions. The call to the sub where the code above is implemented, is inside a loop, however, with each one of the things I've tried, when it gets to the line the program just stops. No error or anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing your code as follows should do the trick.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Site Configuration List")
    .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).EntireRow.Interior.Color = 49407
    .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = Code
    .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = Name
```

Answer (score 2):

The range was not declared correctly. instead of

```
.Range("A").EntireRow.Interior.Color = 49407
```

it needs to be

```
.Range("1:1").EntireRow.Interior.Color = 49407
```

if you want to hightlight the entire row or

```
.Range("A:A").EntireColumn.Interior.Color = 49407
```

to highlight the entire column.

EDIT

To color the last row of data, you'll need to use the `Rows` method, along with the number of the last row that you get from your `Rows.Count`. Code would look like the following

```
Rows(Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).EntireRow.Interior.Color = 49407
```

Or

```
Rows(Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).offset(1).Row) _
                                           .EntireRow.Interior.Color = 49407
```

Comment: How should I put it to color the background of each row I insert? Tried using Rows.Count.End(xlUp).Offset(0) and Rows.Count.End(xlUp).Offset(-1) instead and no luck. Using (1:1) colors the first row, but I want to color the row before I insert the variables into it and I can't put it by hand because that will depend on some condition

Comment: Updated my original post.